# Round up double value in java

Tags: java, format, double

I want to round up a double value in java. Always to round up the value in ispite that matematecally correct way, sometimes, is round down the value. For example:

value = 6.5817

I want to round up, keeping two decimals. So I need the value will be like this:

value = 6.59

The important thing here is always keep two decimals and always round up the second decimal if the value have more two decimals.

Have someone idea how I can to do this in java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153724/5221149)

Comment: He needs it round up with the ceil function so it's kind of different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `double` values are inexact, e.g. it cannot store a number like `0.07` exactly, you need to use `BigDecimal` to help round up a `double` value, with the least probability of getting the wrong value.

To round to 2 decimals, use:

```java
double value = 6.5817;
double roundedUp = BigDecimal.valueOf(value).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP).doubleValue();
System.out.println(roundedUp); // prints 6.59
```

Note that this code prints `0.07` when `value = 0.07`, unlike e.g. `Math.ceil(value * 100.0) / 100.0`, which **incorrectly prints `0.08`**.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
double a = 6.5817;
Math.ceil(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Comment: Since doubles are inexact, you get incorrect results like `a = 0.07` -> `0.08`, i.e. it rounded up a number that didn't need rounding.